# Get post id from inside posts_where wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I get the post id from inside posts_where?

in my code below, $page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); works on pages, but not posts. I've setup a second variable, $post_id, and would like to fill that with the post's id.

Here's my function/filter:

```
// Filter posts
    function ugrestriction_filter( $where, $wp_query )
    {
        global $wpdb, $post, $current_user, $wp_query;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $post_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

        $meta_key1    = '_ugrestriction';
        $meta_key1_value  = 'on';

        $postids=$wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
          "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = 'on'", "_ugrestriction"
        ) ); 


        //$postids = array("70", "1", "2", "3");

        if (in_array($post_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } elseif (in_array($page_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } 


        if ( $filter == 'on') {
          $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_ugrestriction' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'on' AND " .  $wpdb->posts . " .post_author =". $user_id .")";
        }

            return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'ugrestriction_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: you have to understand first that a post's id is less usefull because of the version tracking that wordpress does.  The better question may be how to get the slug for a post?

Comment: A slug would do nothing to help me in this situation.... I need an ID......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Filter posts
    function ugrestriction_filter( $where, $wp_query )
    {
        global $wpdb, $post, $current_user, $wp_query;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_id = $current_user->ID;
        $page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
        $post_id = $post->ID;

        $meta_key1    = '_ugrestriction';
        $meta_key1_value  = 'on';

        $postids=$wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
          "SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s AND meta_value = 'on'", "_ugrestriction"
        ) ); 


        //$postids = array("70", "1", "2", "3");

        if (in_array($post_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } elseif (in_array($page_id, $postids)) {
          $filter = 'on';
        } 


        if ( $filter == 'on') {
          $where .= " AND ($wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = '_ugrestriction' AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value = 'on' AND " .  $wpdb->posts . " .post_author =". $user_id .")";
        }

            return $where;
    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'ugrestriction_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: This works! looks like my problem is with $postids. When on a page, this works and but not on posts.